# AzureWebJobsStorage options for production

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to run Azure Durable Functions on premises. I have set up a durable task MSSQL provider already.

Now, I want a timer-triggered durable client and it is achievable with the `[TimerTrigger]` attribute. I also can run it locally by using `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`.

I have a question: what are the options for web jobs storage for production besides Azure?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run it on-prem one neat option is to use an existing on-prem SQL Server and you can use this package to integrate the durable task with SQL Server
https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-mssql

Comment: I have tried this and it works fine with HTTP triggers but timer-based triggers do not work unless I specify a good value for the `AzureWebJobsStorage` parameter (`UseDevelopmentStorage=true` works as well).